# Apart from Individual users and Teams channel , whom can we send message (with Adaptive card) from bot framework

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams

I Am able to send messages to individual users and general channel of a team using Bot Framework. What I want to know if it's possible to send messages to below target audiences!

1. Private channel of a Specific Team
2. Any M365 Group and Azure AD Security Group
3. Any Distribution list

If possible , any link or documentation would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely message to a regular channel in a Team, aside from the "general" channel, but I've not tested a Private Channel. I don't see why not though, provided the bot has been added to that specific channel.

Aside from that, there's also a Meeting as well as a Group Chat.

But all of those are within Teams. An M365 group, or distribution group, you can message as well, but not within Teams as there's no Teams context. Remember though, that a Teams bot is built on the Microsoft Bot Framework, which can be used to built bots of other types outside of Teams, e.g. web chat, facebook, slack, etc. Included is the possibility to build an "email" bot - it uses the same concepts, e.g. "dialogs" and what not, but communicates via email. See more at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-email?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

Comment: First of all , thank you so much for such a quick response. I will check the feasibility of sending messages through regular channel and private channel tomorrow and get back to you. I am using proactive messaging here to send message to general channel. That means I already have conversation id . For regular channel I need the same kind of ID i guess?
Now coming back to the groups (M365, Distribution groups) , as I understand , they will receive the messages via Email?? Does bot framework provide in built methods for this or I have to use Normal C# code to send email?

Comment: Yup, the concept is the same, just that the channel gets it's own ID, and within a channel or group chat, you have the ability to "reply" to a message (there's no "threading" in a 1-1 chat, so "reply" is just the next message).

Comment: For Email, I haven't used it with a bot myself, but in concept yes it's just sending email, like c#. The difference is that it provides context, so you could have an ongoing dialog with the user, for example or Actionable Messages, that kind of thing (more here on that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/adaptive-card)

Comment: Hello @Hilton Giesenow, thanks for pointing me to right direction. I have tried sending messages to Regular channel as well as private channel. I have followed this [link](https://www.vrdmn.com/2020/02/microsoft-bot-framework-v4-send.html) to test my functionality. The code works for Regular channel and general channel but throws FORBIDDEN error for private channel. I got a documentation which says that private channel doesn't support bots.[link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/private-channels#what-you-need-to-know-about-private-channels). I guess there is a limitation then?!

Comment: ah interesting, didn't know about the limitation for private channels, thanks.

Comment: Other channels you've got working now though it sounds like?

Comment: Yes @Hilton Giesenow. For other channels it is working. Only thing is as a prerequisite, you have to install the app in the team (Regular/General channel) where you want to send the messages . Moreover , this whole thing works for any Private team as well.

Comment: And @Hilton Giesenow , thanks for looking into this issue. I know this is not a right place to tell but I am a big fan of your videos and articles related to bot's capability. :)